# Keycloak custom audit logging

Tags: json, logging, keycloak, audit-logging

is it possible to make custom audit logging format ? Now my audit log, when someone log in, looks like this:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-10-12T12:40:35.28Z","sequence":196127,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.events","level":"DEBUG","message":"type=LOGIN, realmId=<realm>, clientId=https://lernwelt.fraunhofer.de, userId=<user_id>, ipAddress=<ip>, auth_method=saml, redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=<code_id>, username=<username>, authSessionParentId=<session>, authSessionTabId=<sessoin>","threadName":"default task-3501","threadId":90136,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"30e10b105fc4","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":2160}
```

i want to add some user attributes to the audit log in message field (like mail, cn and so on.) But i can't find the place where this is configured, can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.